# How to Receive and Post data to Website from Android app

Tags: android

- I want to Receive Response and Post data from Android app to fill a Registration Form.
- I want to access a website which returns `session_id` from the first page. 
  Means when App get start, I will access the Home page and get the `session_id`, using that `session_id` and some fields in my App, I want to post the data to server of website.

What should be used to do the above Task ?

I have used **Jsoup** and Parse HTML to get `session_id` ( not in Main Thread ), Succeed ,

But How to post data ? I used Another activity to load the next page of website but it shows session expired. I also find other options like using  `HttpURLConnection` , But I don't get an appropriate Example. I am new bee to android . Please help if know.

Answer (score 0):

use Android Volley , http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

this is all about network solution in Android.